# Create a first visit popup in react application?

Tags: reactjs, popup

How do I make a first visit popup for my react application? Is it possible to implement using the [react-popup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-popup) module? I used this module below but it does not seem to work. Can you check and let me know what wrong here.

Below is my homepage:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './HomePage.css';
import Carousel from 'nuka-carousel';
import HeaderComponent from '../../components/Header/Header.js';
import {Decorators} from './decorators.js';
import Popup from 'react-popup'


export default class HomePage extends Component {
    redirectPage = () => {
    window.location = '#/dashboard';
}

componentWillMount(){
  Popup.alert('my component')
}

render() {
    var mixins = [Carousel.ControllerMixin];
    return (
        <div>
            <div className='explore-button-container'>
                <button id='exploreBtn' onClick={this.redirectPage}>Explore</button>
            </div>

            <HeaderComponent id='header' location={this.props.location}/>
            <Carousel
                autoplay={true}
                autoplayInterval={3000}
                wrapAround={true}>
                //Carousel Content
            </Carousel>
        </div>
    );
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In componentDidMount you cann Access the localstorage and the sessionStorage, where you can set a flag, if this is the first visit. 
something like this:

```
class myComponent(){
    constructor(){//do stuff here}
    componentDidMount(){
        let visited = localStorage["alreadyVisited"];
        if(visited) {
             this.setState({ viewPopup: false })
             //do not view Popup
        } else {
             //this is the first time
             localStorage["alreadyVisited"] = true;
             this.setState({ viewPopup: true});
        }
    render() {
        return(<Modal
                aria-labelledby='modal-label'
                autoFocus={false}
                style={modalStyle}
                backdropStyle={backdropStyle}
                show={this.state.viewPopup}
                onHide={this.close}>
                  <div style={dialogStyle()} >
                    I'm the Popup Text
                  </div>
                </Modal>);
     }
}
```

This is how i solved it with Modal, but I'm sure you can do it with Popup, too. If you want to view the Popup on every first visit of a session you can use the sessionStorage instead of the localstorage.
Keep in mind that you have to set the styles. You can see an example here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/react-overlays/

Comment: Thank you. It's working. But I want to know what shall I define under backdrop style. And when I click outside the modal, the modal doesn't hide directly but shows some glitch(small animation) and then hides.

Comment: please have a look at the link provided : https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal there are examples for the styling. Also be aware of setting the State in componentDidMount. I just did it, because I haven't seen another way to access the storages. In this case it works well, but in other cases setting the state in this function can result in problems in the Layout

Comment: sorry, had the wrong url, this is it: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/react-overlays/

Comment: any idea how can I implement this with hooks?

Comment: It wouldn't help if user visit page from 2 different devices ? Should flag come from server side for such cases?

Answer (score 0):

Yea, you can add pop-up as soon as you logged-in or landed-in your page.

In your component, add the following snippets

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './HomePage.css';
import Carousel from 'nuka-carousel';
import HeaderComponent from '../../components/Header/Header.js';
import {Decorators} from './decorators.js';
import Popup from 'react-popup'


class HomePage extends Component {
    redirectPage = () => {
    window.location = '#/dashboard';
  }

    componentWillMount(){
      Popup.alert('my component')
    }

  render() {
      var mixins = [Carousel.ControllerMixin];
      return (
          <div>
              <div className='explore-button-container'>
                  <button id='exploreBtn' onClick={this.redirectPage}>Explore</button>
              </div>

              <HeaderComponent id='header' location={this.props.location}/>
              <Carousel
                 autoplay={true}
                 autoplayInterval={3000}
                 wrapAround={true}>
                 //Carousel Content
              </Carousel>
        </div>
     );
   }
  }
}
```

componentWillMount() is a lifecycle hook, which will execute the set of statements before rendering your concern components.

And, go through all [lifecycle components available](https://ihatetomatoes.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/react-cheat-sheet.pdf) for react.

Comment: Post your component, i will try it and say it to you .

Comment: did you add componentWillMount(), inside your class. you can add this component anywhere, but before render

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in replying. I updated the question with the component. Can you please check and let me know the error.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Dont close your component before rendering your component. now it will work. I suppose

Comment: I don't understand. Why is componentWillMount put inside redirect function? Redirect will take it to another component which I have mentioned there. I want the message to appear on this component when it renders.

Comment: Why do you want an component , only for redirection.

Comment: Have you went through react tutorials?

Comment: Bro, I want to render the popup in this component. Your code includes componentWillMount under redirect function. The redirect function is called when a button is clicked on the homepage. So how is it going to work? Did you understand my point?

Answer (score 0):

Put some indicator in the Setting, e.g. AsyncStorage, then check if it is the 1st time running the app:

```
try {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@isAppFirstTimeRunning');
  if (value !== 'true'){
    // not first time running
    ShowThePopUp();
  }
  else {
     AsyncStorage.setItem('@isAppFirstTimeRunning', 'true');
  }
} catch (error) {
  // Error retrieving data
}
```

Comment: For React Native