# Only show Popup one time with React (local storage)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I would like to show the popup only one time with React Hooks.

1. Access for the first time to `example.com/campaign/1234`
2. Show popup
3. Close or refresh the page.
4. Access again to `example.com/campaign/1234` and don't show popup
5. Access for the first time to `example.com/campaign/0000` (is a different URL)
6. Show popup
7. Close or refresh the page
8. Access again to `example.com/campaign/0000` or `example.com/campaign/1234` and the popup is not being displayed

Any idea of how to do it? I know that I need to use `local storage` but how can I trigger the event when the user closes or refreshes the page?

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/one-time-popup-zlxvw?file=/src/App.tsx).

I also read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882300/create-a-first-visit-popup-in-react-application) but it doesn't mention how to do it with Hooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you never use the `setStickyState` callback from the custom hook, the state will just remain at its initial value.

It seems like `setStickyState` also has a bug in it, where it won't update if the key has changed. Here's an enhanced version that I've called `useLocalStorage`, which should work more reliably:

```js
export function useLocalStorage(key, initialDefault) {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(() => {
    const localStorageVal = localStorage.getItem(key);

    return localStorageVal !== null
      ? JSON.parse(localStorageVal)
      : initialDefault;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem(key) === null) {
      setVal(initialDefault);
    }
  }, [key, initialDefault]);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(val));
  }, [val, key]);

  return [val, setVal];
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```js
const [visited, setVisited] = useLocalStorage(pageId, false);

const navigateAway = useCallback(() => {
  setVisited(true)
}, [setVisited])

useEffect(() => {
  // if user navigates away to a completely different site
  // or refreshes the page etc
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", navigateAway);

  // if user navigates to another page on the same site
  return () => {
    navigateAway();
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", navigateAway);
  };
}, [pageId, navigateAway]);

// ...

<dialog open={!visited}>
  <p>Welcome to page {pageId}!</p>
  <button onClick={() => setVisited(true)}>
    Don't show again on this page
  </button>
</dialog>
```

Here's a demo (with TypeScript):

[`useLocalStorage` demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/uselocalstorage-dodj9?file=/src/useLocalStorage.ts)

Comment: That's the whole point of using your custom hook instead of normal `setState`. Try it and see.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that won't work, because once the component is mounted will set the state and the popup won't be visible the first time.

Comment: In that case, use the callback where it's needed. `<PopupCloseButton onClick={() => setStickyState('visited')} />` etc.

Comment: what if the user doesn't click the popup and refresh the page? 

Comment: Ah, I see the problem now. I think it's partly due to a bug in the `setStickyState` hook. Edited answer.